# Jquery Button in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp

Hi friends in my project their is requirement,As u see i want to convert anchor tag to button look.
This is my jsp code correct me where i am wrong the css link are perfect.
upon the click of anchor tag it should toggle.thanks in advance

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fotorama.css"/>

    <title>Islam WedLock</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/fotorama.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <s:head />
    <sj:head jqueryui="true" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // set effect from select menu value

           $("#button").button();

           $( "#button" ).click(function() {
                $( "#effect" ).toggle("blind");
                return false;
            });

           $.subscribe('hideTarget', function(event, data) {
                $('#'+event.originalEvent.targets).hide("blind");
                $( "#effect" ).hide();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <%@include file="header.jsp"%>

        <!-- content -->
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="demo">
                            <a href="#" id="button">Upload Files</a>
                        <div id="effect" style="display:none;">
                            <s:form action="fileUpload" method="post" theme="xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                <s:file name="userImage" id="fileinput" label="User Image" />
                                <sj:submit targets="result" effect="blind" effectMode="show" onEffectCompleteTopics="hideTarget" value="Upload" button="true" />
                            </s:form>
                            <br/>
                            <img id="indicator" src="progressbar.gif" style="display:none" alt="loading"/> 
                        </div>
                       </div>     
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <sj:div onEffectCompleteTopics="hideTarget" cssClass="ajaxdiv" cssStyle="display:none;" id="result"></sj:div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
   </div>


      <!-- End -->
        <%@include file="footer.jsp"%>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

try using like,

```
< a href="#" id="button"
style="background: #ddd; color: black; border: 2px outset #555">
Upload Files< /a>
```

Ur anchor tag ll look like button...